# Magento Test Framework(MTF) Change the default Behaviour of frontend/backend - Magento 2.0.1

Tags: magento2, testing

I am learning about Magento Test Framework, I had good knowledge about selenium webdriver with java but in magento I am newbie. I have successfully install MTF. I have run one sample test, it will affect the frontend(Adding unnecessary categories in header).

My question is

**How to run the test without affecting frontend/backend?**

Answer (score 0):

By default, there is no way to run functional tests without affecting frontend/backend.
Sure you can create some db dump and rollback to it after each tests or variation, or simply clean up the category after verifying and creating it.

But this is a testing tool, so I don't see any problem that after running test on some testing environment you will see some data on it.

As we don't perform rollback after each test, it saves time. As a plus it discovers additional bugs that won't be found if we will have only one category on store front. If we are going to be as closer to merchant as possible, we should have more than one product and one category.

Clean up is performed only in that test cases that can affected executing another test cases, for example creating catalog rule.

In order to use isolation in MTF you need \Magento\Mtf\System\Isolation\Listener class. For this you specify annotation '@isolation' for test case or test with corresponding value before|after|both. It will call the script dev/tests/functional/isolation.php

Comment: thanks @lanken. I felt little scare when we make any mistake in flow it will corrupt whole frontend/backend. backup is the only option in your point of view right.